# Change a textview text and position when you click and then click again go back to the original

Tags: java, android

Hello i am new in Android apps, so i want your help.

So basically what i am trying to do is to change the content of textview from "Read more" to "Read less" and then when i click again to change back to "Read more". Then my second question is how can i change my textview position from my main activity (java not xml) when i click "Read more", and when it's clicked again to go back again to the original position.

This is my main activity:

```
TextView  paragraphmore;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        paragraphmore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.paragraphmore);
        // hide until its title is clicked
        paragraphmore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


    public void toggle_contents(View v){
        paragraphmore.setVisibility(paragraphmore.isShown()
        ? View.GONE
        : View.VISIBLE );
        TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.readbutton);
        view.setText("Read less");
        }
```

these are the textviews:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/readbutton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/readbutton"
android:clickable="true"
android:onClick="toggle_contents" 
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textSize="11sp">
</TextView>

<!--content to hide/show -->

<TextView  android:id="@+id/paragraphmore"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/paragraphmore"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textSize="11sp">
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
        Log.v("View.VISIBLE", ""+View.VISIBLE);      //0

        Log.v("View.GONE", ""+View.GONE);            //8

        Log.v("visible", ""+paragraphmore.getVisibility());

        if(paragraphmore.getVisibility() == 0){
            paragraphmore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.setText("Read Less");
        }else{
            paragraphmore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            view.setText("Read More");
        }
```

Comment: That worked!! Have you any idea about the other part? (positioning)

Answer (score 0):

1) change the content of textview from "Read more" to "Read less". 
 I suppose you need to set a boolean variable (e.g. private boolean readMore) to listen the behaviour of the textview. Set in the xml "android:onClick" property for the paragraphmore button:

public void onTextClick(View v) {
    readMore = !readMore;
    if (readMore) readMore();
    else readLess(); }

In readMore() method you set textview's text to "Read more" and in readLess() method you set textview's text to "Read less". 
 
 2) how can i change my textview position from my main activity (java not xml) when i click "Read more", and when it's clicked again to go back again to the original position. 
 You can, for example, set a Point (or 2 int) (or Rect if your use all 4 margins, or just int[]) variables to save your view's previous margins. sth like that:

```
MarginLayoutParams params = (MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams(); //http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html
margins[0] = params.leftMargin;
margins[1] = params.topMargin; //and so for [2] and [3]
```

then in onTextClick method you save your view's current margins to local variable and set new view's margins to previously saved, and change previously saved margins to local variable content:

```
public void onTextClick(View v) {
   //...
   int[] newMargins = new int[4];
   MarginLayoutParams params = (MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams(); 
   newMargins[0] = params.leftMargin;// and so on...
   params.setMargins(margins[0], margins[1], margins[2], margins[3]);
   margins = newMargins; 
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: No it didn't help. It can't be done that way. I tried with LinearLayout with setMargins but I cannot get the "Read Less" to the position I want because it moves all the text. So I think the problem is that is in ScrollView all the textviews, and it can't be done that way. Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is in LinearLayout. Try to make it a RelativeLayout

Comment: Well, I tested the case when second textview has property android:layout_below="@+id/textView01" and it changed it location automatically after textView01's content grew.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Click listener on the TextView and compare the GravityFlags on click (forgive my c#/mono syntax):

```
var readbutton = new TextView(this)
        {
            Text = "positon",
            LayoutParameters =
                new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(200, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent)
        };
readbutton.Gravity = GravityFlags.Left;
readbutton.Click += (sender, args) =>
        {
            var tvGravity = readbutton.Gravity & GravityFlags.Right;
            readbutton.Gravity = tvGravity == GravityFlags.Right ? GravityFlags.Left : GravityFlags.Right;
        };
```

where `readbutton` is the TextView that you wish to change gravity for

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer. I understand that working with absolute positioning or margins layouts will do no good to my app, because then I will have problems with when the app will go from one device to another device with different resolution. So I created a new clickable textview that I could manage it's position and then I changed into the main activity my toggle_content method, in order to make invisible first the less textview and then the more textview after it was clicked.

```
TextView paragraphmore;
TextView readbutton;
TextView readbutton1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    paragraphmore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.paragraphmore);
    // hide until its title is clicked
    paragraphmore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    readbutton1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.readbutton1);
    // hide until its title is clicked
    readbutton1.setVisibility(View.GONE);   
    readbutton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.readbutton);
    readbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
}


public void toggle_contents(View v){
    Log.v("View.VISIBLE", ""+View.VISIBLE);      

    Log.v("View.GONE", ""+View.GONE);            

    Log.v("visible", ""+paragraphmore.getVisibility());
    paragraphmore.setVisibility(paragraphmore.isShown()
    ? View.GONE
    : View.VISIBLE );


    if(paragraphmore.getVisibility() == 0){
        paragraphmore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        readbutton1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        readbutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    else{
        readbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        paragraphmore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        readbutton1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    }
```